Export MySQL Database form Flex Server Azure Database
I was doing some classes on PowerBI and needed to connect Azure database with MySQL and then to PowerBI, but i am receiving empty tables.
Is it possible to export the mysql database from the azure portal? I can access cloud shell and make querys, but the query i find in the internet is for a local case.
If that's not possible, i have the whole script to create a schema and fill it. How could i do it to make this database and export it to csv or excel?
I tried to make the connection in PBI, but again, it is just empty tables, while the values can be found in azure.

Please check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

Follow the below steps to export data from Azure MySQL DB to Power BI.

Below is the sample data stored in Azure MySQL Flexible Server.



Open My SQL in Azure portal and click on Power BI and select particular db which you want to view in the Power BI.


Click on Get Started then one file will be downloaded to the local machine. Now, open that file, it will open in Power BI. Click on Get Data and select MySQL DB.


Provide required details like admin, password then it will show as below, now click on checkbox and click on Load.


Then the data will be loaded successfully into the POWER BI as shown below.



